Did the answer about the terminal velocity of the Falcon 9 deserve to be deleted?
This answer now has two votes to undelete and there's no method for giving feedback on a deleted answer, so it's either start a chat about it or start a meta post. Or do nothing, I guess, but I've been repeatedly maligned about my delete vote and comments on the post--to the point it's been called gaslighting!--and frankly I'm angry about that.

Yes, it should be deleted.
As I'll argue below, the answer meets at least two of the criteria explicitly laid out in the help pages:

The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
not even a partial answer to the actual question

and can be shown to be harmful under the same rationale that indicated we should ban LLMs:

Wrong answers that look like they might be right are harmful.

Why is this a bad answer

It's wrong. See below. So wrong that how wrong it is wouldn't have fit into the comments on the answer. There's simply too many things to criticize.  That's one of the explicit criteria for using the delete privilege: The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement. The answer would have to be literally completely rewritten from the ground-up to be improved. See below.

It's not immediately obvious that it's wrong.  A lot of effort is put into it.  It's got charts and equations and pictures!
Why is that a problem? It's part of the basis of why we ban LLMs:

... the posting of content created by ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies is substantially harmful to the site and to users who are asking questions and looking for correct answers.
The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies produce have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like the answers might be good ... without the expertise or willingness to verify that the answer is correct prior to posting.

Wrong answers that look like they might be right are harmful. This site is a trusted source of information for people who don't have the expertise or the free time to evaluate a question like "what's the terminal velocity of the empty Falcon 9 in landing configuration" themselves.

Phil's response to being told the answer was wrong wasn't to correct the answer. It was to fiddle with it.


Why it's wrong

The initial "tl;dr: ~133 km/hr" is an absurd precision for what's later claimed as +/- 100km/hr. There's no basis for that precision figure. It's a guess at best. Even if all the following weren't true, offering that tl;dr is incorrect even for the (incorrect) conclusions drawn.
Until I asked some friends to evaluate the crazy-rantiness of this post, I didn't appreciate how terribly broad that range of speeds is.  33km/hr to 233km/hr!  Probably between bicycling speed or light aircraft speed!  That isn't an answer!

The methods used are non-physical. You can't draw a line on an velocity/altitude plot to extrapolate the velocity as a function of altitude. There's no reason to expect to be able to do that.
Terminal velocity on a velocity/altitude plot would show as a horizontal velocity line (i.e. the booster is now falling at a constant velocity, its terminal velocity). The obvious implication of that is that you would extrapolate a velocity/altitude curve that flattens.  Not a line that proceeds diagonally downward.
The paragraph under that plot is doubly-revealing:

The amount of extrapolation needed here was more than I would have liked.

If Phil didn't even like it, why did he post it as an answer?

Even if linear extrapolation was valid, because the data points he got make a little wavy curve he drew two apparently randomly-sloped lines and chose a point between them as his "extrapolation!" What in the world?! That's not extrapolation, that's hand-waving!

Even if that the extrapolation was valid, which it isn't, extrapolating to zero altitude doesn't get you terminal velocity! It gets you impact velocity! Terminal velocity would show as a horizontal line on that chart! When told that, Phil responded

Wouldn't impact velocity and terminal velocity become the same thing as the booster approaches sea level?

No! Zero altitude doesn't factor in at all. On this plot, zero slope--constant velocity--is the goal state.
So it's not an answer to the right question! It's an answer to a different question--about what the impact velocity would be without the landing burn--except that it would be a bad answer to that question too, because of everything else in this post!

The paragraph under the plot goes on:

Also, there's the question of whether the booster's aerodynamic drag is in equilibrium with the force of gravity acting on the vehicle, or if it is falling faster than terminal velocity because it's still shedding some of its momentum.

Drag being in equilibrium with gravity is the definition of being at terminal velocity for an object that isn't buoyant. That's the question purported to be answered--the velocity at which that equilibrium occurs. If that question remains, the question hasn't been answered!

EVEN IF the extrapolation method was valid AND Phil had extrapolated to the appropriate conditions, the fundamental assumptions of working from the given data are incorrect!

It isn't clear if any of the data points used for the bad extrapolation are in the trans-sonic regime. The coefficient of drag is extremely sensitive to Mach number in those regimes.  So it isn't clear the data is valid.

It isn't clear what the configuration change for deploying the landing legs will do. Assuming it only changes the wetted area, as the answer does, is...wrong.




In the help page about Why and how are some answers deleted?  , the relevant criteria is "not even a partial answer to the actual question."  Even if the question was about impact velocity, it still wouldn't be a partial answer because of just how wrong it is.
Who am I to say it's wrong
I'm an aerospace engineer working as a contractor for NASA at Johnson Space Center. I have multiple pieces of hardware in space, was lead developer for an application that astronauts still use. I'm also an obsessive nerd, and got a reputation for that on the job.
... what would a correct velocity/altitude plot look like, anyway?
I was thinking about making my own spreadsheet to do this, but of course others have come before me (see the bottom of the page). Here's the velocity vs time plot you'd expect to see for an object initially falling faster than its terminal velocity if its coefficient of drag remains constant (I changed the initial values some to get an obvious curve in the time range that already existed):

And here's the velocity vs distance fallen plot:

The only reason to even think about it in velocity vs altitude is that those are the numbers given to us in the webcast. But you have to have some expectation of what the data means to draw conclusions from it!  There are obvious terminal velocities on these charts, but if all you had were noisy points around the "real" values on the left side of the second chart, do you think you'd arrive at the correct "real" value?  Even for this dramatically simplified case?
I shouldn't even have to write an essay about this
It's okay to disagree about whether or not a post should be deleted, or what the appropriate answer to a question is, but come on. This is introductory physics.
OK, so what's my answer to the question then
I don't have one! I don't think there's obviously available data to derive a conclusion from. And I don't answer questions if I don't think my answer will be right.
since the response, I guess I still have to say this?
The thrust of the above isn't about accuracy. The method in the linked answer is incorrect for trying to determine terminal velocity for a number of reasons (above). It does not yield an inaccurate terminal velocity, it just yields a velocity which has no meaning.  Both the method and the number are wrong.
And a credulous reader might decide to apply that method to their own situation. It's worth trying to prevent that.

Even though I agree that Phil‘s answer should be deleted, I disagree that there isn’t enough data to provide an answer - atleast for the falcon 9 with undeployed legs. In the final few seconds before ignition, the falcon 9 is flying at subsonic velocities with the altitude and velocity given. There the deceleration and air pressure can be evaluated. Since F = 1/2 * p * v^2 * A * Cd and F can be replace with m*a, we have all the values except Cd. Once that is calculated, we can replaced "a" with 9.81 to figure out v and that is the terminal velocity of the falcon 9 with undeployed legs

@TheRocketfan well, feel free to do that, but it's still an answer to the wrong question (because it's the wrong configuration) AND you don't know what the pre-burn m is. And how sure are you that the vehicle isn't still transonic at burn time?  But feel free to write the answer

I pretty sure you can find the dry mass of the first stage online and you can see the velocity in the livestream. However, I won’t write an answer because as you agreed, it doesn’t fully address the question. My point was that I think the question is probably answerable, but I’m not intending to provide an answer myself.

Thank you for writing this. I do vaguely recall VTDing for similar reasons... I had thought I looked at a different version but possibly I just got it wrong the second time but realized the issues the first. Retracted my VTUD

The terminal velocity changes with atmospheric density, which is why a velocity vs. altitude chart that covers several kilometers will not show a straight line even if the falling object is at TV the entire time (if I read yours correctly, it covers only 120 cm). Wikipedia claims that the TV decreases by 1%/160m; at 30 km the TV is still  almost 4800 km/h (with remaining fuel though) because the booster is still accelerating in freefall after the deceleration burn..

And personally, I think the deletion was too heavy-handed. The argument that anybody might rely on it is frankly a straw man: The professionals won't, and the amateurs lack opportunity. And in general, the downvote and comment feedback is sufficient.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Whether or not my argument about the answer being harmful is correct, it's not a "straw man".  I didn't take a debate opponent's position and twist it into something it isn't to then argue against my own version; I just connected some ideas about what does or doesn't belong on the site.

@ErinAnne OK, it was perhaps the wrong term. What I wanted to say is: The one argument that mandates deleting the answer is wrong. All other quality issues can and should be handled through the usual mechanisms; the post does not require moderator intervention.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica who said it required moderator intervention? The post was deleted by the community, not mods.

@Erin Oh. I assumed automatically that because you justified the deletion here that you had also deleted it (as mod) and I had not read the banner. Sorry. (I still disagree with the deletion but now my disagreement is less focused ;-). )

Let's start by taking a look closer look at the question
The question has two parts:

What is the terminal velocity of the Falcon 9 at sea level (on Earth)?
Has SpaceX released enough information that this could be calculated with reasonable accuracy?

Now let's look at the answer
After the tl;dr line, the answer quotes the second question again...

Has SpaceX released enough information that this could be calculated with reasonable accuracy?

The second part of the question justifies making an attempt to calculate the value with the limited available information. By illustrating the calculation, and discussing the sources of inaccuracy along the way, the answer gives the reader a better sense of whether "SpaceX released enough information that this could be calculated with reasonable accuracy?"
It doesn't matter if the accuracy of the final answer meets Erin Anne's high standards, because the whole point is to see how well we can do with the available information.
So the first part of the answer is basically:

Here's a calculation, for better or worse, plus
Discussion along the way of the calculation's accuracy.

@ErinAnne represents this discussion as phil1008 flat-out admitting that the answer is wrong. But the whole point of the answer is to discuss whether we're going to arrive at an ill-defined thing called "reasonable accuracy" with the available data.
I finished up by saying

This is still a very rough estimate because the extrapolation step is subject to significant error, the booster may not have been in equilibrium at the altitude where the data points were collected, I didn't account for there being less mass with zero fuel, and - without doing CFD - it is difficult to say how deploying the legs would affect the coefficient of drag.


Squinting at these various sources of inaccuracy, I'd say that my napkin-math estimate is probably a little bit on the high side. But, hopefully, it's still a reasonable estimate.

Now keep in mind that we started out with speed data that was in the 800 to 1000 kph range, and ended up with a value of 133 kph. That value was clearly characterized as "a very rough estimate" arrived at by using "napkin math", so no attempt was made here to misrepresent that the accuracy was great.
Next, let's review the vote-to-delete rules
First, I'm pleased to see that we're restating and trying to follow the rules here. Posts may be deleted if...

The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
not even a partial answer to the actual question

Now the additional criterion in @ErinAnne's answer above is a distraction. "Wrong answers that look like they might be right are harmful." this is something that @ErinAnne added to imply that the answer was deceitful in some way and that by being deceitful it should be deleted.
While I'd be fine with a rule that says that answers containing misleading information should be deleted, it's not currently a rule. I'd personally like it to be a rule - but wiser people than me have probably figured out already that such a rule would be unworkable.
The rules do not say that it's ok to hit vote-to-delete when we think an answer is wrong or inaccurate. We're supposed to talk about it in the comments and we can downvote it.
Thinking it's wrong is not a valid reason to vote-to-delete. The rules are set up this way because becoming a "trusted user" does turn you into someone who is always right. It just means you've been hanging out on the site for a while and you likely can be tapped to do some site maintenance work.
But in this case, the whole point was to execute a potentially inaccurate calculation and discover what we might learn from that process.
To Erin's points...

This is a bad answer because it's wrong.

It would be more accurate to say "...because it's inaccurate". I'd agree that it's inaccurate but the answer is trying to give the reader a sense of what accuracy might be achievable with the available information.
Erin said:

It's not immediately obvious that it's wrong.

Throughout the calculation, the answer makes many points about why the accuracy is poor. For example,

The amount of extrapolation needed here was more than I would have liked.

Erin said:

The initial "tl;dr: ~133 km/hr" is an absurd precision for what's later claimed as +/- 100km/hr.

I stated that the error on an extrapolation step was +/- 100kph, not the final answer. The answer says...

I think the error on the extrapolation is likely in the range of +/- 100 km/hr.

The accuracy of the final value was only characterized verbally as a "very rough estimate". Erin misrepresented that I characterized the 133 km/s value as +/- 100 km/hr, and then made some points about how ridiculous that was.
Erin's said:

Until I asked some friends to evaluate the crazy-rantiness of this post...

We should pause here to consider this "crazy-rantiness" metric. Which post sounds more like a crazy rant? Is it phil1008's answer that was deleted or ErinAnne's answer about why it should have been deleted?
Erin's said:

The paragraph under that plot is doubly-revealing:

This isn't "doubly-revealing, it's "disclosure". I'm calling attention to a source of inaccuracy - which is the point of the exercise.
Erin's said:

Phil's response to being told the answer was wrong wasn't to correct the answer. It was to fiddle with it.

Well, judge for yourself...

Erin's said:

If Phil didn't even like it, why did he post it as an answer?

Again, this illustrates that Erin didn't understand that the answer was attempting to illustrate a calculation to see if reasonable accurately could be achieved.
Erin said:

If that question remains, the question hasn't been answered!

(...referring to a remark made in the answer "... the question of whether the booster's aerodynamic drag is in equilibrium with the force of gravity acting on the vehicle, or if it is falling faster than terminal velocity because it's still shedding some of its momentum.")
There's an attempt here to set a dangerous precedent. What's being described is a process whereby:
a) A trusted user spots a remaining question,
b) They declare the question "unanswered" because of the remaining question,
c) They are then free to apply the "not even a partial answer to the actual question" criterion and can vote-to-delete it.
Clearly, the writers of the rules anticipated this, which is why they said "not even a partial answer". But it gives us a window into the mind of someone who seeks to bend the rules as much as possible.
Is there room for improvement?
Yes, Erin was confused about which of the two questions the answer was trying to address first (even though it was restated right at the top of the answer) and the approach being taken. I put too much faith in the tilde in the "tl;dr ~133 km/hr" statement.
I think that someone who is obsessive might just look at the value in the tl;dr statement and say "There's no way to come up with a number that accurate." - which is true. But then they might just skim the text to see how the calculation was done, and only look for evidence to affirm their belief that the answer is inaccurate.
I think that more careful readers will read the post and understand that the answer is really about getting a feel for whether we can do some napkin math and arrive at an answer with "reasonable accuracy".

"While I'd be fine with a rule that says that answers containing misleading information should be deleted, it's not currently a rule." - it doesn't have to be a rule. If a quorum of trusted users believe the content to be low quality, it can easily be deleted. This is by design. Having answers that are incorrect but suggesting we can do some napkin math is not helpful here - this is not a discussion forum. If you can post an answer with accurate data, and back it up with citations, then folks will be much happier.

Wrong/Misleading answers are definitionally not useful or helpful and should be deleted.
